# jQuery animation screwing up when switching tabs

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, jquery-animate

I have a simple animation on my page that cycles through quotes (from a javascript array, currently). Before a new quote is loaded, jQuery moves the div to the right a bit and hides it. Then it loads the new text and moves the div back to the left while fading it in.

Here is the

### JavaScript:

```
var lastIndex;

$(document).ready(function () {
    cycleTestimonial(); // set first testimonial
    setInterval(cycleTestimonial, 9000);    // cycle through testimonials every x seconds after that
});

function cycleTestimonial() {
    var testi = getTestimonial();   // retrieve testimonial
    if (!testi) return; // usually means duplicate of last quote, so skip setting HTML
    $('#testimonial').hide(0, function () { // erase current quote
        $('#testimonial > #quote').html(testi['quote'].replace(/'/g, "&rsquo;"));
        $('#testimonial > #author').html(testi['auth']);
        $('#testimonial > #tagline').html(testi['tag']);
        $(this).velocity({   // set opacity to 0 and move right instantaneously to prepare to fade new quote in
            right: '-=60',
            opacity: 0.0
        }, 0, function () {
            var testiH = $(this).height();
            var headH = $('#home-header').height() / 2;
            $(this).offset({ 'top': (headH-(testiH/2)) });
            $(this).show().velocity({    // fade in new quote and slide left
                right: '+=60',
                opacity: 1.0
            }, 600);
        });
    }); 
}

function getTestimonial(index) {
    var t = [   {   "quote" : "I love this product.",
                    "auth"  : "John Doe",
                    "tag"   : "Preferred Client"
                },
                ...
            ];

    if (!index) {   // no specific testimonial asked for, get a random one
        index = Math.floor(Math.random() * t.length);
        if (index == lastIndex) {   // retrieved same testimonial as last time
            cycleTestimonial(); // re-run until we get a new testimonial from last time
            return;
        }
        else lastIndex = index; // set to ensure no repeats back-to-back
    }
    return t[index];
}
```

For thoroughness, here is the corresponding

### HTML:

```
<div id="home-header">
    <div class="boundary">
        <div id="testimonial">
            <div id="quote">
                quote
            </div>
            <div id="author">
                author
            </div>
            <div id="tagline">
                tagline
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

And, finally, relevant

### CSS:

```
.boundary {
    display: block;
    position: relative;
    margin: 0 auto;
    max-width: 1080px;
    min-width: 720px;
    height: inherit;
}

#home-header {
    display: block;
    position: relative;
    height: 420px;
    width: inherit;
}

#home-header #testimonial {
    position: absolute;
    display: block;
    top: 40px;
    right: 0px;
    min-width: 350px;
    max-width: 470px;
}

#home-header #testimonial #quote {
    display: block;
    width: inherit;
    text-align: left;
    font-size: 26pt;
    font-style: italic;
    line-height: 1.2;
    color: #0085df;
    font-weight: 300;
}

#home-header #testimonial #author {
    display: block;
    width: inherit;
    text-align: right;
    font-size: 14pt;
    font-weight: 700;
    color: #999;
}

#home-header #testimonial #tagline {
    display: block;
    width: inherit;
    text-align: right;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    font-weight: 400;
    font-size: 8pt;
    color: #999;
}
```

Now, this code works great most of the time. However, **when I switch away from the page to a different tab or window**, and then come back to it, the alignment is all screwy until a new quote is loaded.

Also, **when I load the page**, occasionally the alignment gets screwed up then too, like it was placed before the page was fully loaded or loaded enough for it to place properly.

Is there a better way to do what I'm doing that won't come with these issues on placement?

Comment: Most likely this happens due to nested `setInterval`s. Switch the outest interval to `setTimeout`, and add another `setTimeout` to `cycleTestimonial()`.

Comment: @Teemu Thanks, I'll try that. And in that case, I wouldn't actually need the `setTimeout` call at first, would I? Just call `cycleTestimonial()` in `$.ready()` and then place `setTimeout(cycleTestimonial,9000)` at the bottom of `cycleTestimonial()` itself, right?

Comment: Yes, that's fine. Nested intervals are usually bad, since the calls are cumulated, if the called function can't be executed after interval. This happens in many browsers (not in IE though) for example when visiting another tab for a while.